# Changing Deeply Nested Object Value

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

This seems to be obvious, but i can't figure out how to shortening change deeply nested object value in multiple places in the code without retyping each time keys path to this value:

```
> obj = { 'key1': { 'key2': { 'key3': { 'key4': { 'key5': 'value' }}}}}
> obj.key1.key2.key3.key4.key5
'value'
```

---

```
> obj.key1.key2.key3.key4.key5 = 'changeme'
> obj.key1.key2.key3.key4.key5
'changeme'

> obj.key1.key2.key3.key4.key5 = 'changeme2'
> obj.key1.key2.key3.key4.key5
'changeme2'
```

Comment: `var x = obj.key1.key2.key3.key4` ... then make changes to `x.key5`

Comment: If you want a purely command-line solution, just press up arrow. Otherwise, just store a reference to `let ref = obj.key1.key2.key3.key4;` and use `ref.key5 = 'changeme3';`

Comment: Adding to @JaromandaX comment, reason this would work is because you are assigning an object. Objects are assigned using reference. Hence change in one place will reflect everywhere. But if you set `x= ...key5`, it will not as primitive types are copied by value

Comment: ah, that was nice! i indeed tried to  assign `value` directly with no luck :+) i.e `var x = obj.key1.key2.key3.key4.key5` thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could assign the innermost object to a variable.

```
var foo = obj.key1.key2.key3.key4;
```

From there on out, accessing/modifying `foo.key5` will be equivalent to accessing/modifying `obj.key1.key2.key3.key4.key5`.

```
foo.key5 = 'new value'
console.log(obj.key1.key2.key3.key4.key5); // 'new value'
```

Comment: Though this has been addressed in comments, please add explanation as to how this works and why not assign `x` till `key5`

Answer (score 9):

You could use a bit of recursion to iterate over every key in your object and update where it finds a matching key.

```js
const obj = { 'key1': { 'key2': { 'key3': { 'key4': { 'key5': 'value' }}}, 'key5': 'test'}}

const mutateObjectProperty = (prop, value, obj) =>
  obj.constructor === Object && Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (key === prop) obj[key] = value
    mutateObjectProperty(prop, value, obj[key])
  })
    
mutateObjectProperty('key5', 'updated', obj)

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify()`, `JSON.parse()`, `String.prototype.replace()`. You can also use a `RegExp` that only checks property name, instead of both property name and value.

```js
var obj = { 'key1': { 'key2': { 'key3': { 'key4': { 'key5': 'value' }}}}}

function updateObject(obj, key, val, value) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)
         .replace(new RegExp(`"${key}":"${val}"`), `"${key}":"${value}"`))
}

obj = updateObject(obj, "key5", "value", "changeme");

console.log(obj);
```